# Roo deprecated roo method

Tags: ruby, xls, roo-gem

Using roo gem on Windows with the following code:

```
require 'roo'
require 'roo-xls'

workbook = Roo::Excel.new 'test.xls'
```

I get message to STDOUT

```
[DEPRECATION] extend Roo::Tempdir and use its .make_tempdir instead
```

The code works fine after that, I am able to do everyting I want. However, I want to get rid of this message (without making a new class or anything like that, it's just opening a file... right?). How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct fix would be to not use the deprecated method and instead use the recommended one. However, in this case, it's not you who is using the deprecated method, [it's the author of `roo-xls`](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo-xls/blob/master/lib/roo/xls/excel.rb#L30):

> ```
> make_tmpdir do |tmpdir| # …
> ```

So, the only things you can do are:

1. file a bug report against `roo-xls`, preferably with a pull request fixing the issue (actually, the former [was already done for you](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo-xls/issues/28))
2. for the time being, [suppress deprecation warnings](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/blob/master/lib/roo/base.rb#L547) until the upstream issue is resolved; Roo uses [`Kernel#warn`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-warn), so you can unfortunately only turn off all warnings, but something like this should work:

   ```
   original_warning_level = $VERBOSE
   $VERBOSE = nil

   workbook = Roo::Excel.new 'test.xls'

   $VERBOSE = original_warning_level
   ```